# Provoke in a good way

Tags: synonyms

What is the word for provoking some one in a good way to do something good? My research shows provoke is means to induce anger in a person to do something. I have found "inspired" but it doesnt give the same provocative :) effect.

Cheers

Comment: Hebrews 10:24 (KJV)
and let us consider one another to provoke unto love and to good works:

Comment: How about `engaging` someone?

Comment: @TecBrat -- would you hold that sentence from the KJV as an example of good modern English?

Comment: How about ["provoked him into a realization of spiritual potentiality"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GNnQVfjGUCoC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%22provoked+him+into%22&source=bl&ots=ljQZzqD2nb&sig=EukZwgLySxW4m7u863DmVof4KNg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fmD1UpO5GdGThgedkoGQCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22provoked%20him%20into%22&f=false) or ["provoked him into writing his most enduring works of fiction, and his greatest poetry"](http://www.sundialpress.co.uk/Peter_Tait_EMMA_West_of_Wessex_Girl.html)? Provoked can certainly be used for positive actions in modern English.

Comment: @simon I don't claim that it's an every-day usage, but I think the OP's situation might call for something that is less common. The fact that it _is_ less common actually gives it more weight to the hearer.

Comment: To TecBrat's point, provoke has a neutral denotation, my answer below suggests keeping it if the context is positive.

Comment: http://biblehub.com/hebrews/10-24.htm Other translations have spur, motivate, stir up, stimulate, encourage, excite, and arousing. Provoke is probably the most common one, but may be partially inspired by the KJV.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

*Inspire* and *encourage* are clearly positive, but not as strong.

*Provoke* is generally negative as you say, though if used of a good thing then it **could** work well, precisely because it would be a use that is unusual—whether it's so unusual to jar or just unusual enough to stand out well can't be judged out of context, and there would likely be some disagreement if we did see the full sentence.

*Spur* is perhaps a good choice. Edit: some people are objecting to spur, they've a fair point, but I hope none of them ever ride horses ;)

*Incite*, *foster*, *hearten*, *embolden*, *induce*, *stimulate*, *persuade*, *coax*, *instigate*, and *urge* are all words that overlap enough that they might suit your purpose but not so much that they necessarily would.

Edit: *Stir* works in some cases too, and while it's a bit old-fashioned in this sense, I personally like it.

Comment: I like *spur*, but in some cases, to merely *prompt* or *stir* may suffice.

Comment: +1 I agree with provoke being used in a way that isn't necessarily negative. For instance by itself provoke is associated to be negative, but when I've heard the phrase "thought provoking" it doesn't have the same negativity, for me anyways.

Comment: *‘Take this ring, Master,’ he said, ‘for your labours will be heavy; but it will support you in the weariness that you have taken upon yourself. For this is the Ring of Fire, and with it you may **rekindle hearts** in a world that grows chill. But as for me, my heart is with the Sea, and I will dwell by the grey shores until the last ship sails. I will await you.’*

Comment: Is spur not somewhat negative as well? As in it takes someone poking you with a wheel of sharp spikes to get you to do whatever it is they want you to do? ('prod' would be similar too)

Comment: @frozenkoi, in theory at least, spurs deliver mild but persuasive encouragement.

Comment: @choster, just saw your suggestion of *stir* after adding it to my answer. Personally I am biased towards it because "I do summon, stir, and call you up" is part of my liturgy, which makes it hard to tell if I'm being fair in judging it good enough to compensate for a rather old-fashioned flavour, but I definitely like it for some reason or other.

Comment: I find your answer satisfying and on the target but i kind of agree with frozenkoi. Spur is what you do to a horse and it is actually forcefull imo. So spurring a person foesnt sound really polite but in absence of a better word i think its the best option. I have also come across the word "Fillip". What do you guys think about that?

Comment: On its own, I think of _stir_ in a more negative sense (_stir up trouble_, for example). That said, any of these (including _provoke_, really) could be used positively in the right context.

Comment: How about 'entice'? (English is not my first language)

Comment: @drumfire *entice* is fully positive, though it may be too much so; if they either offered a reward or else made the action they are encouraged to do seem particularly pleasant in itself, then you would have the mot juste, but otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: The question asked for positive words of encouragement. Spur is hardly positive in most contexts. Spurs look cool, but no one wants to be goaded in the ribs with spurs.

Comment: @Feral - Most human spurring is more figurative than that. Many things can spur us on, besides those cool, pointy wheels – like desires for vengeance, wealth, success, or love. NOAD mentions three ways to be spurred: _urge (a horse) forward by digging one's spurs into its sides; give an incentive or encouragement to (someone); cause or promote the development of; stimulate_. I'd say two out of those three could be used in positive context: _Knowing she'd be allowed to get her driver's license if she made the honor roll, Beth was spurred on to study harder._ That sounds better than _provoked_.

Answer (score 9):

"**arouse**" comes to mind also. Though, be careful when using, it can be too positive sometimes.

Comment: +1, despite the fact that it can also have a sexual connotation.

Comment: @KyleStrand That's what was meant by "too positive sometimes." :)

Comment: I @SoylentGreen I guess you're right, sex is pretty positive!

Comment: One case in point, the NIV 2011 translation of the Bible [swapped](http://www.slowley.com/niv2011_comparison/words/niv1984_provoked.html) out provoked for aroused, although each instance was specifically in reference to anger.

Answer (score 8):

Words that come to mind when thinking of "provoking" but with a positive connotation would be:

- motivating
- prompting
- driving
- encouraging
- incentivizing

Answer (score 6):

How about *challenge*? To challenge someone to to something. It seems to me it fits the bill for positive provocation.

Answer (score 4):

How about the the word "rouse"?

rouse: to kindle to intensity :  excite, inflame

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rouse

Comment: How about *kindle* itself?

Answer (score 4):

Galvanize sounds like the word you are looking for.
Galvanize
1. (verb) to shock or excite (someone), typically into taking action.

Comment: Alternately in the "terms inspired by science" category, I'd suggest **catalyze** as a bit more mainstream.

Answer (score 3):

[*Stimulate*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=stimulate&t=crmtb01) implies an action by one person upon an other, just as does provoke.

Answer (score 2):

I actually like "provoke" in that context, but if you really need something different, you might try [spur](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/spur%5Bverb%5D)

**EDIT**, to show that spur is frequently used in a positive sense.

A google search for *spur to success*  brings up headlines like these:

- Did the JFK Assassination Spur the Success of the Beatles?
- Steelers notebook: Johnson helps spur success in red zone
- Accelerating Startup Success to Spur Economic Growth
- Can the Lumia 2520 Spur Nokia and Microsoft to Success?
- Coaches Spur Advisers To Hit Bigger, Better Success

Comment: I just realized that Jon Hanna included "spur" in an earlier answer.

Comment: The question asked for positive words of encouragement. Spur is hardly positive in most contexts. Spurs look cool, but no one wants a goad in the ribs with spurs.

Comment: @FeralOink Please see my edit.

Comment: They are somewhat masculine examples e.g.  Pittsburgh Steelers, sports team coaches, tech start-up's (which shouldn't be gender-specific, but generally are), but I'm not complaining. I am a woman, and wouldn't find spur to be a word of positive encouragement. Most prose is not gender-specific though, so spur is probably just fine in a general sense. It is *much* better than "stimulate", "lure" or "arouse"!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the word [exhort](http://english.answers.com/definitions/exhortation-definition-and-examples) before. I am not sure what its connotations are. In the linked webpage it says it has a positive connotation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for "**spark**" - it clearly has positive connotations (to me at least)

> These bright students have **sparked** her enthusiasm for teaching.
>
> The
>   arrival of the piano player really **sparked** the party. (from [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spark))

Answer (score 0):

*Provoke* can have negative connotations, but it denotes: "stimulate or give rise to (a reaction or emotion, typically a strong or unwelcome one) in someone."

So I would not rule out your original inclination, if based on the context you make clear that it is positive reactions or emotions you are attempting to arouse.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *provoke*, which may have negative connotations, such as goading or irritating, consider ***[pique](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101450/is-it-peek-peak-or-pique)***.

> Attending the lecture series **piqued** my interest in further study.

That is a positive usage of pique, similar to provoke in its more positive form of *provocative*. Similarly, there is a negative form of pique, "a fit of pique" e.g. "Gaddafi left enriched uranium on the runway in '**[fit of pique](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1335585/WikiLeaks-Gaddafi-left-enriched-uranium-runway-fit-pique-U-S-visit.html)**' after he felt snubbed during U.S. visit". As long as you use pique as a word, not part of a phrase, there will be no confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little uncommon, but you could also use impel.  I believe this has a neutral connotation, so it might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised [**invoke**](http://gog.is/define+invoke) hasn't already been mentioned.

It is very similar without the negative connotations.

> e.g. He gave a passionate speech that invoked a positive attitude amongst the attendees.

[**Compel**](http://gog.is/define+compel) could also be suitable for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the word "pay"...i.e. Could you do this for me, I'll pay you this much. Or give you this in exchange.

Otherwise it seems like you're asking someone to do something they don't want to do, for no reason? Unless you mean "blackmail", "slavery", "brainwash" ??

If you're strong enough in some area, you can use "threaten" (induce fear of reprisal).
For instance if you're a nation-state, weapons, imprisonment, etc.

You can take away things someone might have, if you can control that. Privacy, freedom, food, water, shelter, entertainment.

Comment: Who are you? It makes me feel happy to read this. It is ethical and fair and honest and true and just so good in every way.

Answer (score 0):

ermanen's answer above provoked me to laughter. The word appears to me to be negative or positive only according to context.

But to the point: I should ***nudge*** you in the right direction. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**stimulate** could be good enough if it is used in biological sense.

Answer (score 0):

There was a popular acronym, AIDMA used among ad men when I was still in the frontline of business, which represents for Attention→Interest→Demand→Motivate→Action.

In other words, AIDMA illustrates the process of how the advertisement works, and how the massage lets people take their actions (good for the advertiser).

Although I’m not sure of if this word is still in use in advertising world, I would like to suggest “Motivate” as the word you’re looking for. 
"Encourage" (to do sth) could be another alternative.

Answer (score -1):

"evoke" and "elicit" ...or perhaps even "enthuse"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. A good answer provides an explanation as to *why*, including appropriate links or references, so that the questioner as well as future visitors can understand the reasoning. For additional guidance on how to use this site, please see the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score -1):

[Tiger mother](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tiger-mother) (BrEng) or tiger moms (AmEng) are said to **push** and **drive** their children towards academic excellence.

> In terms of academic achievement, British Chinese children are the
>   most successful ethnic group in this country, and behind each success
>   story you will usually find a formidable Tiger Mother. Play by her
>   rule book, and you get hours of homework and music practice, strict
>   discipline, and not too much time for play. But you are also more
>   likely to get A grades.

'A Michigan State University scholar has refuted [tiger mother](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/buzzword/entries/tiger-mother.html) philosophy that parents should **drive** their children to succeed even at the expense of the kids' happiness.'